# User agent issue renders unreadable tag html source data

Tags: html, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

Opening the [following URL code inspection](https://www.cvs.com/shop/cvs-health-anti-diarrheal-caplets-prodid-1011910) in Chrome yeilds the following message:

> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

And the code behind the site looks like this:

```
<div dir="auto" class="rn-13yce4e rn-fnigne rn-ndvcnb rn-gxnn5r rn-deolkf rn-cme181 rn-1471scf rn-14xgk7a rn-1b43r93 rn-o11vmf rn-ebii48 rn-vw2c0b rn-t9a87b rn-1mnahxq rn-61z16t rn-p1pxzi rn-11wrixw rn-wk8lta rn-9aemit rn-1mdbw0j rn-gy4na3 rn-bauka4 rn-q42fyq rn-qvutc0">24 Count</div>
```

Opening the same link in Internet Explorer seems to render the tags properly, for example: gbcvs-c-addToCart__inner can be found.

Selenium is used to read the page, and it used to work with Chrome. Is there a way to set the user agent knowing the program will run in Linux?

I tried the following with no luck..

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"')
```

I would like to keep using the chrome driver.

Comment: I did notice that using 64 bit Internet Explorer Webdriver does not garble up the HTML code and I am able to read the required attributes. What is the difference between how the request is handled with IE vs Chrome? (IE, not Edge!)

Comment: For this of us in the EU the website blocks us :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to do it, but for chrome you can use a plugin like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US) to fake your user agent header. When using chrome from Selenium you can then [load that extension](https://intoli.com/blog/chrome-extensions-with-selenium/) and use it to change that header for all requests.

Comment: Is this different than setting the user agent directly in the chrome options in python?

Comment: Only if setting it directly is impossible, which your question seems to say is the case. The extension would bypass the security check.